# É possível alterar o valor de uma variável que foi decorada com Input()?

Tags: angular

Tenho a variável ***disciplinasTurma*** que foi está recebendo um valor do componente pai. Eu queria remover um dos valores dela, o método até remove, mas só dentro dele mesmo. Tem como fazer isso?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mutação no geral é ruim, o certo seria copiar pra outra propriedade

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar um método set para esse fim.
Dessa forma você executa uma lógica antes de passar o valor para a sua variável de classe.
Por exemplo:

```
@Input()
set disciplinasTurma(disciplinas: string[]): void {
    this.disciplinasTurma = disciplinas.splice(disciplinas.findIndex(d => d === valor), 1);
}
```